# ElasticSearch 5.1 geo distance range query deprecation?

Tags: elasticsearch

According to the the Elasticsearch 5 release note listing [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_search_changes.html) , the geo_distance_range query is no longer supported. 
Eventhough the official documentation doesn't state such a change, using this API is printing an error :

```
[geo_distance_range] queries are no longer supported for geo_point field types. Use geo_distance sort or aggregations
```

The suggestion is to use bucket aggregations instead of the geo_distance_range query feature. 
But aggregations are by nature something quite different from applying a search filter (possibily in combination with other filters).

Is there any way to achieve the same thing as this feature originally provided in previous versions of Elastic search ?